# Firefox sometimes grinds Windows to a halt and has a dozen instances running with strange command lines

Tags: windows-7, firefox

This just started happening recently: occasionally my computer will grind to a halt when Firefox has been running for a while with a lot of tabs and windows open.  When I can finally get Process Explorer open, I see that there are a dozen instances of the Firefox process running, and a lot of them have strange command lines like this:

[image]

Googling the issue does not bring up anything useful, though I can't seem to figure out the most-effective way to phrase the query.

What the this all about?  What's going on, and how do I stop this from happening?

I'm using Firefox 60.0 (64-bit) with Windows 7 Pro SP1, 8 GB RAM Intel Core i7 2.7 GHz 8 processors.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why are you running the 32-bit version of Firefox on a 64-bit Windows operating system?  You said that it is the 64-bit version, but that screenshot clearly says `C:\Program Files (x86)`, which is indicative of the 32-bit version of the web browser.

Comment: It's definitely 64 bit version of Firefox.  It says so in Help/About and also in Process Explorer.  I have no idea why it's running from the x86 prog files.

Comment: Backup your profile and uninstall FF completely. Verify there are no longer entries in either ProgramFiles location. Then reinstall the 64bit version and see which location it creates entries in. This may be leftovers from a previous/failed version upgrade.

Comment: @music2myear -- What issue is your comment addressing?  I don't care about it being in the wrong prog files folder if that's the only thing your suggestion addresses.

Comment: Rory.ap , the point that both @music2myear and I were making is that your Firefox may be "grinding to a halt" because of past errors within the application install and/or configuration.  You shouldn't have a `firefox.exe` file within the `Program Files (x86)` folder hierarchy.  As a result, he was recommending that you completely uninstall Firefox, reboot, and ensure that you don't have a `Mozilla Firefox` folder under either `Program Files (x86)` or `Program Files`.  If they persist, delete them.  Then, install the 64-bit version of Firefox and see if the problem has been alleviated.

Comment: Ahh, I see.....

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look into this yet.  Thanks for checking in, though.